# jQuery .get() data from JSON formatted data and refreshing some DOM element to display it

Tags: php, jquery, json, socket.io

I have heard about technologies like socket.io, but it is too advanced for me.

I created PHP file that displayes JSON formatted data in array.

I use the jQuery function `.get()` with the URL `datafile.php` to get the string and display it in the pages. I use timer loop for this `.get()` and it is run every few seconds. This is how I simulate updating texts without refreshing the page.

But I really think if it is the right way of doing this. is there some better approach?

Here is my current script (the highlights classes are only to make little flashing on the element to show that value has been changed):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.total-xp .number').addClass('highlighted');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.total-xp .number').removeClass('highlighted');
    }, 1500);
    $.get("data.php", function(data) {
        $(".total-xp .number")
                .text(data.total_xp_data)
    }, "json");
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments. You should look at socket.io. Socket.ios allows your server to push data updates to subscribed clients when they happen, thereby saving on wasteful polling for updated data from every attached client, this is pretty much accepted practice. I've no personal experience on socket.io however I've use Signal R in .NET for these kind of problems and found it works well.

Second. I would be tempted to return json to your client, then your client can render the data as appropriate. Then if you need another interface to present the data you don't have to write  another server side method, or if you need to change your UI you don't need to reploy the server side components.

If your really can't face the effort of socket.io then your solution will work, it will be hard to get anyone to agree it is best practice.